# How do I prevent lines from overlapping in Draw.IO

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I am making some drawing where I am making a diagram of how physical cables connect into electrical pannels. My issue is that the lines ends up overlapping. I know I can separate them "permanently" by using Waypoints.

But is there a way to have them be separated automatically?

My current issue:

[image: Issue]

What I am trying to achieve:

[image: Goal]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.